# Select multiple list type columns from Koalas/Pandas Dataframe and construct a new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, spark-koalas

I have a dataframe where each row looks like this:

```
Pandas(Index=0, a=array([0.78420993, 0.61972316, 0.46183716, 0.48915005, 0.77913277,
       0.06024269, 0.81624765, 0.88517468, 0.13920925, 0.1065294 ]), b=array([0.77951759, 0.66244447, 0.9437135 , 0.96207391, 0.78377241,
       0.70583409, 0.29280931, 0.81172593, 0.10672919, 0.77779754]))
Pandas(Index=1, a=array([0.41687065, 0.42237762, 0.55709948, 0.90720451, 0.01000812,
       0.82060544, 0.74241916, 0.62584166, 0.07328964, 0.66590757]), b=array([0.81446728, 0.10341285, 0.7268244 , 0.25971413, 0.0834643 ,
       0.2000305 , 0.86025538, 0.79984722, 0.71790545, 0.44250095]))
Pandas(Index=2, a=array([0.42444138, 0.00104965, 0.51756438, 0.61498706, 0.05810544,
       0.84679377, 0.33802997, 0.66426461, 0.52571041, 0.19639958]), b=array([0.17096899, 0.06315944, 0.31988078, 0.07621797, 0.84541187,
       0.56356022, 0.00256211, 0.69829937, 0.69287602, 0.124942  ]))
```

What I would like to do next is grab the columns "a" and "b" and create a new dataframe where each row is a sequential element from their lists. So something that looks like:

```
a                         b
0.78420993                0.41687065
0.61972316                0.77951759
```

I am currently using a combination of Koalas and Pandas on a Databricks notebook using pyspark and do plan to run on a Spark cluster. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this (keeping performance in mind) would be very helpful!

Comment: I don't understand the logic completely - do you want that every element of the array became a separate row?

Comment: yes exactly. is that possible?

Comment: are arrays in a & b always the same size?

Comment: Yes arrays in a and b will always be the same size